# How is a plantuml diagram with nested boxes oriented vertically?

Tags: plantuml

I am trying to made a diagram that grow vertically (with the trick of hidden arrows to down), but plantuml is still drawing horizontally.

This is a tiny example of diagram

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho
top to bottom direction

rectangle aaa {
  rectangle aaa111
}

rectangle bbb {
  rectangle ccc {
    rectangle ccc111
    rectangle ccc222
    rectangle ccc333
    
    aaa111 -right-> ccc111

    ccc111 -[hidden]-> ccc222
    ccc222 -[hidden]-> ccc333
  }
  rectangle ddd {
    rectangle ddd111
    rectangle ddd222

    ddd111 -[hidden]-> ddd222
  }
  rectangle eee {
    rectangle eee111
    rectangle eee222

    eee111 -[hidden]-> eee222
  }

  ccc -[hidden]-> ddd
  ddd -[hidden]-> eee
}
@enduml
```

[image: The example tiny diagram]

And this must be like:

```
aaa -> ccc
  
       ddd

       eee
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Do you want the ccc, ddd and eee rectangle to be stacked vertically?

Comment: Yes, ccc, ddd and eee stacked vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not logical, but `left to right direction` will do it:

```
@startuml
skinparam linetype ortho
'top to bottom direction
left to right direction

rectangle aaa {
  rectangle aaa111
}

rectangle bbb {
  rectangle ccc {
    rectangle ccc111
    rectangle ccc222
    rectangle ccc333
    
    aaa111 --> ccc111

    ccc111 -[hidden]left-> ccc222
    ccc222 -[hidden]left-> ccc333
  }
  rectangle ddd {
    rectangle ddd111
    rectangle ddd222

    ddd111 -[hidden]left-> ddd222
  }
  rectangle eee {
    rectangle eee111
    rectangle eee222

    eee111 -[hidden]left-> eee222
  }

'  ccc -[hidden]-> ddd
'  ddd -[hidden]-> eee
}
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML image]